# Javascript: How to check whether an element is "displayed" on the screen?

Tags: javascript, css

**Step 1:**

When I change the value of the `display` property of an element using JavaScript by something like:

```
document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display = "none";
```

it changes what I see in the browser, but it does not change anything in the server side HTML script.

**Step 2 - Problem here:**

The problem is that after the above step, I later have to check if `#myDiv` is displayed on the screen. If it is, I do something. So I need to use a conditional expression like:

```
if (document.getElementById("myDiv").style.display == "none") {
    //do something here
}
```

But problematically this expression never evaluates to `true`, because step one did not change anything on the server side HTML.

**So I need a way here to check in JS whether an element is displayed on the screen?** How can I do that?

NOTE:- Don't suggest JQuery. I can't use it.

Comment: All it should be changing is the inline css for the element. It shouldn't change anything else.

Comment: What you have works fine -> **http://jsfiddle.net/b70sx6zL/**

Comment: Where do I see the results of `console.log` in JSFiddle? @adeneo

Comment: *"Where do I see the results of console.log in JSFiddle?"* Where you normally see them.

Comment: @amphetamachine Well I am new to web programming, I used to see the console output in my IDE in the desktop programming languages. For JS, I used this function in the IDE of codeacademy.org, and rest I don't know. I don't know where the console for the web programming is. SO that's not a reason to downvote my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have *should* be working. Yes, running

```
[...].style.display = "none";
```

does not change the server-stored HTML; **however**, when you check for that same property,

```
([...].style.display == "none")
```

you are checking the **inline** styles, which **are** set by the first line.

---

For example, running

```
document.getElementById("aDiv").style.display = "none";
```

Will set the inline style property of `#aDiv`:

```
<div id="aDiv" style="display: none;">
```

---

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/33b0aq57/1/)

Answer (score -1):

Use the visibility property.

`visibility: visible|hidden|collapse|initial|inherit;`

`document.getElementById("myDiv").style.visibility = "hidden";`